# Missing realm constructor react native ios but realm is linked

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, realm

Keep getting the Missing Realm Constructor error and have tried everything from the [Realm documentation on this common issue](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#troubleshooting) to relinking with `rnpm link realm` which tells me they're already linked. I've also tried linking in Xcode by adding in the `libRealmReact.a` file manually, but all to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few long hours of debugging and going through GitHub issue articles (and posting one of my own), I found [this article](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1128) where the solution is to set the Realm variable as null for load, but to define the variable in the constructor as so:

```
const Realm = null;
constructor() {
    if (Realm === null) { Realm = require('realm'); };
}
```

The issue is that there is some sort of timing issue where Realm doesn't load before the view itself instantiates.

Comment: assigning variable to null and checking for null. I think this will not make any difference.

Comment: Read the last line. The error is thrown if Realm is imported because Realm for whatever reason doesn't load before the view instantiates. The check for null is to prevent a memory leak of Realm pointers for every time the class loads

Answer (score 0):

For me following steps worked, here version of realm npm played major role -

step1

```
npm install --save realm@v3.3.0

react-native link realm
```

step2 : Run(build) XCode project target named 'RealmReact'

step3 : Link binary with library for your project, add framework named 'libRealmReact.a'

That's all if the above steps didn't work, try to delete test target of RealmReact.xcodeproj

```
 your xcode project->Libraries->RealmReact.xcproject->Test target for this linked project
```

Answer (score -1):

For now, you can add this line in your Pod file:-

pod 'RealmJS', :path => '../node_modules/realm'
pod 'GCDWebServer'

Comment: i tried this but this dosn't seem to work